# How to change the font smoothing setting from the command line?

Tags: macos, font

I'm trying to avoid installing lots of software willy-nilly, because like so many Mac users I don't have antivirus software. Case in point, I really like TinkerTool but I'd rather change my system wide settings from the command line than use someone's program for that.

So, how can I change the system-wide font smoothing setting from the command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int <1-3>` as far as I remember